# Selenium Webdriver .then() on findElements?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Ill preface this with that i've never used selenium-webdriver as a standalone driver. I've generally used it with wrapper/dsl frameworks (Capybara for Ruby) or using automation with newer frameworks (Cypress/Playwright).

Im looking at some older code that was written and trying to understand why/how something was written. I noticed what looked like callback hell with selenium find elements and waiting. I've seen selenium samples before....but they've never really looked like this. here is an example of a portion of a chain of commands:

```
driver.sleep(1000).then(function(a) {
        driver.findElement(locators.baseURL)
        .sendKeys("www.widgets.com");
        driver.sleep(1000).then(function(b) {
                driver.findElement(locators.someKey)
                 .sendKeys("AVALIDKEY");
                 driver.sleep(1000).then(function(c) {
                        driver.findElement(locators.somethingElse)
                        .sendKeys("SOMETEXT");
                        driver.sleep(1000).then(function(d) {
                                driver.findElement(locators.anotherLocator)
                                .click();
                                driver.sleep(6000).then(function(e) {
                                etc......
})})})})})
```

Goes on like this for some time. So i'll be honest, while im familiar with some selenium i've not seen it used this way before. This is also older code (probably 4-5) years old.

My question is: is this a normal coding pattern for selenium? I understand it does not have auto-waiting build in like cypress or playwright. But I feel like there has to be a better way? Or is this maybe why selenium isn't as preferred these days?

If you are doing a LOT of commands like this, how does one clean up the waiting of elements when they are one after another. Does selenium support async/await?

From my understanding selenium was written to "look" synchronous but act async under the hood. So with that being said is this how selenium scripts "should" look?

As a secondary question: Wouldn't all these sleeps add up to a test that would take multiple minutes to run? Unless selenium doesn't wait the full time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just wrap it in an async function and then you can use await:

```
async function run(){
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  await driver.findElement(locators.baseURL)
    .sendKeys("www.widgets.com");
  await driver.sleep(1000)
}
run()
```

It's probably technically bad practice to use sleep like that.